# Align a list with end of text

Tags: lists, itemize

I am looking to create something like:

[image: Example]

where I can define a list that is shifted and aligned to the end of some introductory text.

While I could hardcode a solution for specific text, how can I achieve this for variable introductory text and list items?

Comment: I've seen a question like this before... But I can't find it.

Comment: Do you want the list to be "attached" to the end of regular text, like a previous paragraph? Or separated text? And what if the text is too long than a single line?

Comment: I guess attached to the end. The text being too long won't be a problem in my case, but that is an interesting consideration to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `enumitem` and `calc` packages to create a somehow half automatic solution.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{description}[labelwidth=\widthof{Intro text:}+.5em,%
                        leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax]
        \item[Intro text:]
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \item item 3
            \item etc.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Another solution could be this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\addtokomafont{labelinglabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    \begin{labeling}{Intro text:}
        \item[Intro text:] \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \item item 3
            \item etc.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{labeling}
\end{document}
```

But you would also have to specify the longest label.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to wrap the list in a `minipage`. This adds extra spacing, which you can reset with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Intro text:
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, label={--}]
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
    \item etc.
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]